# how to read from a file that is constantly appended to by another program c++ linux

Tags: c++, file, io

so i have one process that is writing to a file. A new process i am creating will open this file, and ideally read any changes to it and process them.

so far in the class that controls this i open the file

later on in a different function I constantly do reads on it to check for changes and process them

it vaguely looks like

```
open(file);
while(1)
{
fread(buffer, 1, 16000, file);
//do something 
}
```

problem is, i have been debugging it by having it pull in an empty file and then writing to it after it has been opened. the FILE object never sees any of the changes.

do i need to close on eof and reopen again? the top in order to get the changes to work?

Comment: You have to close the file after writing before reading from it.

Comment: @BlackMoses: Not necessarily. This is Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Use `file.clear()` to clear the EOF indicator so you can read past the old EOF.

Comment: `fread()` is C, not C++.

Comment: actually, in C, it's `clearerr`.

Comment: Have you tried `inotify`? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: so it turns out my code was fine. i was using vim to edit the source file, and apparently it wasnt saving my changes until after my program shut down :x i used nano to edit it and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach to that suggested by dbush:

```
/* declare buffer, file and open file */
size_t rc;
while (1) {
   if ((rc = fread(buffer, 1, 16000, file)) == 0) {
       if (feof(file))            {
           clearerr(file);
           usleep(100);
       }  else {
           /* it's a real error, not EOF */
       }
   } else {
       /* process rc bytes in buffer */
   }
}
```

Comment: i did put a clearerr in, but it is not the problem. the problem is when i open that file in an editor and add to it (i use vim), save, and close while still debugging the program, the program doesnt see that the file is changed and returns 0 for for bytes read.

Comment: The above code works when the file is being appended to (i.e. new data is added beyond the current position of the FILE pointer). If you edit the file and shorten it, `fread` will attempt to read beyond the end of file and never see changes. If `tail -f` works in your test case, so will the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fseek` to jump to the end of the file, then `ftell` to see your offset.  If it changed from the last time, you know there's more data.

```
int current = 0, last = 0;

FILE *f=fopen(filename, "r");
if (!f) {
    perror("can't open file");
    exit(1);
}
while (1) {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    current = ftell(f);
    if (current != last) {
        printf("len=%d\n",current);
        fseek(f, current, SEEK_SET);
        last = current;
        fread(buffer, 1, 16000, f);
        ....
    }
    usleep(100);
}
```